# ERROR:mi_fifo:mi_fifo_check: security: fifo_check: inode/dev number differ: (/tmp/opensips_fifo)

Tags: sip, fifo, sip-server, opensips

I am new to opensips and have installed it a few days ago. I have got it to make calls. But i am facing a problem with mi_fifo module. It is giving the following error

> ERROR:mi_fifo:mi_create_fifo: fifo_write did not open: Bad file
>   descriptor
>
> ERROR:mi_fifo:mi_fifo_server: failed to read command
>
> ERROR:mi_fifo:mi_fifo_check: security: fifo_check: inode/dev number
>   differ: 3643 1391 (/tmp/opensips_fifo)

This error keeps bundling on the syslog file and takes all the space on the server. I have somehow made some arrangements to keep truncating the file every 20 minutes but I would be really happy to remove this error. So if someone can help I'll be obliged.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this issue and i somehow resolved it in my case. I went to configuration file in opensips  installation directory and then to etc/opensips.
I commented all the instances where mi_fifo was occurring and then stopped opensips. 
Then I deleted the mi_fifo file in /temp directory.
Then I uncommented them again and started opensips once again. This time I stopped receiving the error.

The problem I identified was that I had more than one instances of opensips running and they were all trying to write on the /temp/mi_fifo file simultaneously which was causing the problem.